# Generate parquet from CSV on the fly in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyspark, parquet, pyarrow

I have multiple very large datasets stored in CSV format on a S3 bucket. I need to convert these CSV to Apache Parquet files.

I don't have (nor want) any Spark cluster, so correct me if I'm wrong, but it seems to me that `pyspark` cannot be of any help.

Basically, from an iterator streaming CSV row by row, I want to generate Parquet files according to a schema.
From my understanding, `pyarrow` can't take an iterator in input.

Does someone have any idea to tackle it?

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Spark can be run locally, e.g. by installing `pip install pyspark` and running code in a local jupyter notebook.

```
spark = SparkSession.builder\
    .master("local[*]").appName("csvConverter")\ 
    .config("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", 8)\
    .getOrCreate()
```

Above initialization will set spark to run in local mode and use as many cores as possible.

With a running spark session locally you can easily load all of the csv using parallel processing capabilities of spark - should be significantly faster than streaming them from files row by row.

```
df = spark.read.format("csv") \
  .option("inferSchema", "true") \
  .option("header", "true") \
  .schema(table_schema) \
  .load("./data/*.csv")
```

There are libraries for reading data from S3.

To save loaded data you can easily write it to parquet

```
df.write.parquet("output.parquet")
```

And that's pretty much all.

If you don't want to create a cluster yourself, take a look on [Databricks](https://databricks.com/). In Databricks creating a cluster is a pretty much one-click exercise, you can use them either on Azure or AWS (Azure provides 200USD [free trial](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/free/search/?&ef_id=Cj0KCQjw_OzrBRDmARIsAAIdQ_L4rDgW8IFaItEzdWreFpcnvuvH8Q4v_ZvXF9k-x2tWhe9aY5NpKzoaAm62EALw_wcB:G:s&OCID=AID2000105_SEM_ihEDHHBQ&MarinID=ihEDHHBQ_369043897124_azure%20trial_e_c__77955621338_kwd-23984383277&lnkd=Google_Azure_Brand&dclid=CIfwmsKyzeQCFdaZGAodtyAL1Q) that you can use). On top of that, Databricks provides a free community edition with 6GB memory clusters [- you can learn more here](https://databricks.com/product/faq/community-edition)

Comment: Thank you for you help.

The thing is, the `csv` files are already stored on a S3 bucket, and I must convert them to `parquet` approximately one time a month. I can only run a Docker container, and imho it may not be a good idea to launch a `spark` cluster in a single container... I'm looking for a non-spark way to do it

Comment: I don't see why them being stored on S3 is a problem - spark can easily read them. If you really don't want to use spark, you can use regular pandas or pretty much any libraries for s3 and csv / parquets. Keep in mind though that if they are actually very large, running spark on a single node is still beneficial as explained in this article: https://databricks.com/blog/2018/05/03/benchmarking-apache-spark-on-a-single-node-machine.html

Comment: @Daniel It seems the problem is our friend here does not have a ```spark``` cluster setup therefore ```arrrow``` on a single node is the alternative.  That article seems more about bench-marking and the integration with ```pandas_udf```.  It doesn't make much sense to use ```spark``` for single machine analytics as it is just wasting money having a cluster just using 1 machine all the time.  Overall ```spark``` is the best framework here for large batch data however the multi-thread ```pyarrow``` process will work too if a cluster is not available but won't scale as well over time imo.

Comment: @thePurplePython Keep in mind that Spark has a local mode that works completely out of the box on a single machine. If you start with Spark you can easily scale, and you have all of the libraries and integrations from the whole ecosystem, which includes using ```pyarrow``` in some scenarios. Will ```pyarrow``` let you handle data larger than available memory?

Comment: @Daniel Well ```local mode``` is recommended for testing, desktop dev, and non-prod jobs.  Also ```pyarrow``` has to be installed on every node in the cluster for it to work with ```spark``` integration.  It just doesn’t make sense to launch a ```SparkSession``` and only use 1 machine in a cluster for a big data use case.  If the single machine w/ ```pyarrow``` has an efficient amount of RAM and CPU and aren’t talking TBs of data then I'd expect the iterative mini-batch process to perform well since it sounds like just converting csv to parquet and writing to ```s3``` in this post scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a code snippet example of reading csv data and then writing it to parquet table.  This is the `pandas` single machine method and does not utilize the distributed method via `spark`.  Hope this helps.

This article provides some nice examples for your iterative batch use case:

https://wesmckinney.com/blog/arrow-streaming-columnar/

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.parquet as pq

PATH = "s3://..."

df = pd.read_csv(PATH, sep="\t")

df.head()
c1  c2  c3
0   1   2   3
1   4   5   6
2   7   8   9

parquet_table = pa.Table.from_pandas(df, preserve_index=False)
pq.write_table(parquet_table, './df.parquet') # target path

! ls ./df.parquet
./df.parquet # list of parquet files

pandas_table = pq.read_table('./df.parquet') # confirm write worked

pandas_table.to_pandas() # data
    c1  c2  c3
0   1   2   3
1   4   5   6
2   7   8   9
```